# C#: How to get fingerprint reader to scan in the background (when app is out of focus/minimized)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk, fingerprint, biometrics

I made an application in Visual Studio using the Digital Persona `SDK` (UareU4500) that simply scans a finger and saves the image to the folder.

I want to add a feature that allows the ability to scan and capture the image even if the application is out of focus. It works fine if it is the active window, however, it does not receive the image, or the listener is obviously inactive when a scan is performed.

I have seen the other similar question here that uses `DPFPCapturePriorityhigh` but I do not really understand how this is successfully implemented.

According to `SDK` documentation, this is used to prioritize captures in a system, not really mentioning how to use it in this case. I have also investigated using a `SetPolicy()` to force data to the application but the concept is confusing and there is not much information on how to do this.

Here is a sample of the code im using from the previous suggestion:

```
private void BackgroundListener()
        {
            rsn = Convert.ToString(0); //(Readers.SerialNumber)
            try
            {
                cp = new DPFP.Capture.Capture(rsn, DPFP.Capture.Priority.High);
                if (!ReferenceEquals(cp, null))
                {
                    cp.EventHandler = this;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't initiate capture operation!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Figured out the answer to my own question. Turns out you initialize the capture class you can initialize the priority within that

ex:  public DPFP.Capture.Capture cp = new DPFP.Capture.Capture(Priority.Low);

Comment: so which one actually works in background, Low or High exactly?

Comment: @Benny seems to be Low. I've tested with High and sometimes stop capturing without reason.